# How to autoscale an app instance with Kubernetes based on just own custom objects in own db (user, time)?

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes

I have read the custom metrics possibilities with Kubernetes, but it is not still clear to me how I can autoscale the Kubernetes pods with Docker image in it based on the custom objects in my postgres database.

Example:
- Instantiate a new app instance if the current app instance reaches X users (a user is an object in psql)
- Instantiate a new app instance if the current app instance reaches Y minuts (a time object in psql)
- Terminate an app instance if no users are there
- All app instances can be instantiated in the same VM (Windows Data center 2016)

Who can provide steps to reach the above?

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, autoscaling a pod is taken care by Horizontal Pod Autoscaling by default, it works out based on the following formula

desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]

Usually it is based on CPU Utilisation metrics, eg: currentMetricValue = 200m and desiredMetricValue = 100m K8s scale your application to 2 pods.

These can be defined in your deployment, here is an example on how horizontal pods auto scaler works. [Horizontal auto scaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#meaning-of-memory)

But from V2Beta2 a newer api is introduced which allows a user to specify custom metrics for the Horizontal pod autoscaler to use.

You can either use these two apis to learn and build custom metrics based on your db queries.

[Custom metrics api](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/custom-metrics-api.md)

[External metrics api](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/external-metrics-api.md)

However, there are few external metrics api already exists which might helpful for you to write the adapter for your needs. [Existing custom metrics apis](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics/blob/master/IMPLEMENTATIONS.md#custom-metrics-api)

Hope this is helpful.